# Updating contacts using google API - Parse Error

Tags: xml, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to update the google contacts by an application. I was trying to achieve that with the OAuth 2.0 Playground provided by google but every time I keep on getting Parse Error!

As described in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ I am making a HTTP PUT request with header If-Match: Etag and the Etag is something like this "QncyejVSLit7I2A9XBZSFU4NQQw."

My XML looks like:

```js
<entry gd:etag="QncyejVSLit7I2A9XBZSFU4NQQw.">
  <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/302be498e51dd8e</id>
  <updated>2008-02-28T18:47:02.303Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <gd:name>
    <gd:givenName>Queen</gd:givenName>
    <gd:familyName>El</gd:familyName>
    <gd:fullName>Queen El</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
    primary="true">456-123-2133</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
</pre>
```

Now my header is

`PUT /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/302be498e51dd8e HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Gdata-version: 3.0
Content-length: 561
Content-type: application/atom+xml
If-match: QncyejVSLit7I2A9XBZSFU4NQQw.
Authorization: Bearer`

But all I get is a Parse Error! Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you literally sending `</pre>` at the end?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I just copied the XML request from Google and copied it. New to web development and I did not know what </pre> is for.

Comment: Remove the </pre> as it's not really part of the picture. All end tags must have beginning tags.